# Android Bundle - Gives different param values

Tags: android, android-bundle

Description:

I am passing values from activity to DialogFragment with help of bundle. I need to fetch/get those values from bundle for my further process.

Problem:
I do not get passed values but I get some other key-value pair which i did not pass/used. - Mapping Issue

Code:

Activity

```
MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();

    Bundle bundleValues = null;
// val1 and val2 are pin values
        bundleValues = new Bundle();
        bundleValues.putString(Params.PIN_VALUE,pinDate);
        bundleValues.putString(Params.PIN_VALUE_1,val1);
        bundleValues.putString(Params.PIN_VALUE_2,val2);

    dialogFragment.setArguments(bundleValues);
    dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"values");
```

Code in MyDialogFragment

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {


        if (bundle.getString(Params.PIN_VALUE) != null) {
            String pinVal = bundle.getString(Params.PIN_VALUE);
            mPinVal.setText(pinVal);
        }

        if (bundle.getString(Params.PIN_VALUE_1) != null) {
            String pinVal1 = bundle.getString(Params.PIN_VALUE_1);
            mPinVal1.setText(pinVal1);
        }


        if (bundle.getString(Params.PIN_VALUE_2) != null) {
            String pinVal2 = bundle.getString(Params.PIN_VALUE_2);
            mPinVal2.setText(pinVal);
        }

    }
```

In MydialogFragment post `bundle = getArguments()` i get below values in bundle as below in image:

[image]

Comment: Make sure you are setting the correct text when you get the string from your bundle. It looks like you are getting the correct string argument, but you are setting "pinVal" (instead of pinVal1 or pinVal2) in all the TextViews.

Comment: @swerly i have updated the code, check once

Comment: You are still using pinVal for setting the mPinVal2 text view text. other than that I dont see any errors

Comment: @swerly setting values into view is not the issue but the value which I want to set is not coming up in the bundle.

Comment: Can you see if the bundle even contains that value? you can use bundle.containsKey(Params.PIN_VALUE_X), and that should return a bool.

Comment: Where did you call `getArguments()`? Make sure you called it in the `onCreateView` and not in  constructor.

Comment: @swerly bundle does not contain that key, that's the issue here, even though I add key-value in bundle it's not coming up

Comment: @NabinBhandari getArguments() is called in onViewCreated()

Comment: Try creating Fragment using static newInstance method.

Comment: @all - the issue is fixed, just restarted android studio and device, thank you all.